# How do I express these sentences in logical symbols?

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

[image]

I am unsure about how to negate the statements in (b) and (c): should I negate the whole thing, including the "for every" part, or only negate the part with the equalities or inequalities?

Comment: You should negate the whole statement as it it asked.

Comment: They probably want you to propagate the negation to the leaves of the abstract syntax tree.

Comment: @Lelouch so for example, (b) should be "the real number r has the property that |r-n|<(1/2) for some integer n."?

Comment: Technically all three can be handled just by replacing "has" with "does not have". It is unlikely this is what they are after, but they should have been more specific. But yes, your previous comment is the negation of (b).